# Subdocument function "pull" and "id" not working in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pull

I am pretty new at mongoose and nodejs so I was doing my project referring to mongoose document. I want to remove a particular subdocument in the comment array by identifing the subdocument with its id. I trried doing it using "pull" as well as "id" method as shown in the image. I couldn't find any mistake in my syntax as well but still it is working.
[image: Img of my code, error in the terminal and the mongoose document I am referring to]

This is sample document from my db:

```
{
  comments: [
    {
      replyComment: [],
      _id: 601a673735644c83e0aa1be3,
      username: 'xyz123@gmail.com',
      email: 'xyz123@gmail.com',
      comment: 'test123'
    },
    {
      replyComment: [],
      _id: 601a6c94d1653c618c75ceae,
      username: 'xyz123@gmail.com',
      email: 'xyz123@gmail.com',
      comment: 'reply test'
    },
    {
      replyComment: [],
      _id: 601eb7ba7233015d7090c6bf,
      username: 'xyz123@gmail.com',
      email: 'xyz123@gmail.com',
      comment: 'test comment'
    },
    {
      replyComment: [],
      _id: 601ec090f5f22d75b41bec7b,
      username: 'xyz123@gmail.com',
      email: 'xyz123@gmail.com',
      comment: 'test comment123'
    }
  ],
  _id: 601a3b8038b13e70405cf9ea,
  title: 'latest test',
  snippet: 'latest test snippet',
  body: 'latest test body',
  createdAt: 2021-02-03T05:58:24.123Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-02-07T06:56:53.902Z,
  __v: 15
}
```

By doing this test findById("601a3b8038b13e70405cf9ea") and console.log(result)
[image: Response of the request made]

My topicSchema file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema =mongoose.Schema;

const topicSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    snippet: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    comments: {
        type: Array,
        required: false
    }
}, {timestamps: true},{ versionKey: false });

const Topic = mongoose.model('Topic', topicSchema);
module.exports = Topic;
```

My commentSchema file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema =mongoose.Schema;

const comSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    comment: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    replyComment: {
        type: Array,
        required: false
    },
}, {timestamps: true},{versionKey: false});

const Comm = mongoose.model('comm', comSchema);
module.exports = Comm;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined `topic` and don't using  `topic = result,` with `,` because it's not necessary
so doing like this :

```
result.comments.id(commId).remove();
result.save()
```

if you want to using `topic` just try

```
let topic = result;
topic.comments.id(commId).remove();
topic.save()
```

for this document you can using  `update` and `$pull` like this:

```
   Topic.updateOne(
    {
      _id: req.params.id,
    },
    {
      $pull: {
         "comments" : { _id: req.params.id1 } 
      },
    },
  ).then((res)=>{
    console.log(res)
  }).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
  });
```

if you can use async/await just try

```
app.delete('/topic/:id/comments/:id1',async(req,res)=>{
  let result = await Topic.findById(req.params.id);
  result.comments.id(req.params.id1).remove();
  let finalResult = await result.save()
  console.log(finalResult)
})
```

and with .then() .catch approach:

```
 Topic.findById(res.params.id).then(result=>{
   let topic = result;
   topic.comments.id(res.params.id1).remove();
   topic.save().then(result=>{
     console.log(result)
   }).catch(err=>console.log(err))
 }
 ).catch(err=>{
  console.log(err)
});
```

**NOTE**: update the mongodb to 4.4 and uninstall mongoose module and install again

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion but still the same error I am getting.

Comment: can you show me the a sample of documents

Comment: yes I have edited the question pls look at it there

Comment: Thankyou Yaser, I have tried all the three methods also input params is also correct for sure, also some other mongoose methods are not working. I reckon there is a problem with mongoose but I am not sure.

Comment: I tested three methods it works fine, do have same error in three method?

Comment: Yaa, the same error in the image. It is showing:
    TypeError: topic.comments.id is not a function

Comment: test findById("601a3b8038b13e70405cf9ea") and console.log(result), show me the result

Comment: Check in the question please I have edited it.

Comment: I've updated my answer, disable version key after that use id().remove()

Comment: Still the same error. Showing .id is not a function.

Comment: can you show me the schema file complately

Comment: Mentioned it in the question.

Comment: what's the mongoose version?? don't use toObject() in your project?

Comment: Its "mongoose": "^5.11.15".

Comment: do you use `toObject()` in your project? why result of find in your project is a plain object javascript? result should be a model of mongoose document

Comment: I haven't used toObject() in the project.

Comment: can you put your project on github and send me the link of project???

Comment: Pls look the git repository link here: [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228411/discussion-between-techie-and-mohammtad-yaser-ahmadi)

Comment: Some other mongoose methods were also not working. Is there can be a possible problem with lodash?? I have used that in my project.

Comment: No,It’s not possible, delete all module and install agian

Comment: Did that still the same

Comment: Just needed a clarification, the comments array in my sample json is a 'primitive arrays' or 'array of subdocuments' ??

Comment: comments array is a `primitive arrays` that have subdocuments(list of comment )